# Would my bank account be tied to the address I anmeldet with?

Tags: germany, banking

I am planning out my life in Germany, and it will be needed that I travel between a few states in the beginning. Hence, this question arised, would my bank be tied to the anmeldung I gave for it? If so, would I have to change the address with bank everytime I move? Thanks.

Comment: Do you _travel_ or do you _move_? Do you rent multiple apartments at the same time, or does one tenancy agreement at one location succeed another in a different location?

Comment: @KaiBurghardt To move, I will probably be moving around some AirBnbs in the beginning

Comment: FYI: the past tense of *anmelden* is *angemeldet*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change address with your bank when you move.  However, if you just temporarily reside elsewhere, you wouldn't be moving.  You need to have an address of permanent residency in Germany, which is where you are registered and where the bank will send you mail.

Note that some banks only operate regionally.  In particular, *Sparkasse* is often linked to a *Kreis* (county) or *Kreisfreie Stadt* (county-free city).  If you move to another county, you won't have any offices nearby.

Comment: which banks operate throughout whole germany?

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom The major commercial ones usually do; the term they use in Germany is *Direktbank*.  There are several online-only alternatives that might be cheaper than those who keep branch offices in cities and even villages.  Unless you value physically going into a bank, the online-only alternatives may be a good choice, as then it naturally doesn't matter where one lives.